# Why the definition of smooth boundary defined like this and how does it imply the interior ball property?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, submanifold

I am trying to understand what the definition of smooth boundary is. From the following lectures notes on analysis 3 :
[image]

So intuitively, a smooth boundary ( in this case , it is a $C^1$ boundary) should have no edges and corners. So I think condition $b$ takes care of that. But why do we have condition $a$?

Also why does having a smooth boundary imply $\Omega$ has the interior ball property?
The interior ball property is : for each $x\in \partial \Omega$, there exists a ball $B \subset \Omega$ such that $x\in \partial B$.

Intuitively, this seems like it should be true, but I don't see how we get from the definition of smooth bondary to this.

Comment: Intuitively to me, condition a) implies a certain “calmness” property of the boundary. If a) fails, then in particular I think it must fail on the boundary itself, in that for all smooth functions $f$, it is the case that there are $a,b\in\partial\Omega$ with $f(a)\le0$ and $f(b)\gt0$, regardless of how you define $f$, so the boundary must be very bumpy somehow... think of trying to change $f$ so that the above is false - if your attempts never work, that says something quite striking about $\partial\Omega$. This is my first take on it, I’ve not studied the subject myself.

Comment: @FShrike oh thats interesting. Also another interpretation I've read is that a smooth boundary means we can "straighten it out" although I don't see how this definition would give us that impression.

Comment: Ah. It could mean the boundary separates what is in the closure and what isn’t: a) requires f be positive outside of Omega

Comment: @Bill The implicit function theorem will allow you to straighten out the boundary.  Note that $\partial \Omega \cap O_a = \{f_a = 0\}$.